# Given 1 billion numbers we need to find the largest 1 million numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

I have been stuck in one question.

Given 1 billion numbers we need to find the largest 1 million numbers. One approach is to sort the
numbers and then take the first million numbers from that is in O(n log n). Propose an algorithm that has
expected O(n) time complexity.

Is it Heap sort which can do that with having O(n) complexity?

Comment: I rolled back the answer since there seemed to be a consensus that the new edits didn't make sense, and the existing answers used the original version. If there is another question with substantially different info you might consider asking in a separate question.

Comment: Heap sort cannot do this with O(n), it is O(n log n) like other comparison based sorts considered to be good.

Answer (score 2):

The general version of the problem you're trying to solve here seems to be the following:

> Given n numbers, report the largest k of them in (possibly expected) time O(n).

If you just need to find the top k elements and the ordering doesn't matter, there's a clever O(n)-time algorithm for this problem based on using fast [selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). As a refresher, a selection algorithm takes as input an array A and a number m, then reorders the array A so that the m smallest elements are in the first m slots and the remaining elements occupy the larger slots. The ***quickselect*** algorithm does this in (expected) time O(m) and is fast in practice; the ***median-of-medians*** algorithm does this in worst-case O(m) time but is slower in practice. While these algorithms typically are framed in terms of finding the *smallest* k elements, they work just as well finding the *largest* k elements.

Using this algorithm as a subroutine, here's how we can find the top k elements in time and space O(m):

```
Initialize a buffer of 2k elements.
Copy the first k elements of the array into the buffer.

While there are elements remaining in the array:
    Copy the next k of them into the buffer.
    Use a selection algorithm to place the k largest elements
      of the buffer in the first k slots of the buffer.
    Discard the remaining elements of the buffer.

Return the contents of the buffer.
```

To see why this works, notice that after each iteration of the loop, we maintain the invariant that the buffer holds the k largest elements of the ones that have been seen so far (though not necessarily in sorted order). Therefore, the algorithm will identify the top k elements of the input and return them in some order.

In terms of time complexity - there's O(k) work to create the buffer, and across all iterations of the loop we do O(n) work copying elements into the buffer. Each call to the selection algorithm takes (expected) time O(k), and there are O(n / k) calls to the algorithm for a net runtime of O(n + k). Under the assumption that k < n, this gives an overall runtime of O(n), with only O(k) total space required.

Answer (score 0):

No general sorting algorithm can do this in O(n) time. Furthermore, without additional constraints (e.g., the billion numbers are taken from the numbers 1 to 1,000,000) there is no sorting algorithm at all that is going to work for this.

However, there is a simple O(n) algorithm to do this:

1. initialize a return buffer with 1,000,000 empty cells
2. for each item in your list of 1,000,000,000, do the following:
3. check each of the 1,000,000 cells in order
4. if the number from the input is bigger than the number in your buffer, swap them and keep going
5. if you're looking at a blank cell, put the number you're holding down
6. if you get to the end of the list and are holding a number, throw it out

Here's an example with a list of 10 things and we want the biggest 5:

```
Input:  [6, 2, 4, 4, 8, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2]
Buffer: [-, -, -, -, -]
        [6, -, -, -, -] … see a blank, drop the 6
        [6, 2, -, -, -] … 2 < 6, skip, then see a blank, drop the 2
        [6, 4, 2, -, -] … 4 < 6 but 4 > 2, swap out 2, see blank, drop 2
        [6, 4, 4, 2, -] … 4 <= 4,6 but 4 > 2, swap out 2, see blank, drop 2
        [8, 6, 4, 4, 2] … 8 > 6, swap, then swap 6 for 4, etc.
        [8, 6, 4, 4, 2] … 2 <= everything, drop it on the floor
        [8, 6, 4, 4, 4] … 4 <= everything but 2, swap, then drop 2 on floor
        [8, 6, 4, 4, 4] … 1 <= everything, drop it on the floor
        [9, 8, 6, 4, 4] … 9 > everything, swap with 8 then drop a 4 on the floor
        [9, 8, 6, 4, 4] … 2 <= everything, drop it on the floor
```

You do 1,000,000 comparisons and potentially up to 1,000,000 swaps for every element in the input (consider input in sorted ascending order). That means you do work proportional to 1,000,000 * n, a linear amount of work in the size of the input n.

Comment: Not sure why are you calling this `O(n)` - this seems more like an insertion sort.

Comment: Rather than keeping the 1M cells in order, make a min-heap of them.  Full ordering is not required, you just compare new candidates to the heap's min, pop it if the candidate is larger and then push the new value.

Comment: @SomeDude It is O(n) with a constant factor of around 1 million. It's a large constant factor, sure, but it's constant.

Comment: @SomeDude insertion sort on a fixed sized list is O(1), just with a large constant.

Comment: @pjs The constant factor can probably be improved upon but this is still O(n). Indeed, there is no asymptotically more optimal complexity ignoring constant factors.

Comment: Note that this is O(n) because we are sorting the fixed-size output buffer, NOT the variable-sized input. Any attempt to sort the input is going to fail for the reasons I discuss at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @Patrick87 Agreed, we both gave the same response to SomeDude.  I'd still favor reducing the constant to proportional to 20 rather than proportional to 1M.  Same basic logic as your answer, though.

Comment: Got it. The buffer is fixed in size. But the number of swaps in the worst case is of the order of 1M*1M agree?

Comment: @pjs Yeah you're right, it would probably result in a faster real solution than this one.

Comment: @SomeDude Probably closer to 1M x 1B (minus a bit since the first 1M numbers checked will go into some blank cell).

Comment: @Patrick87 yes 1Mx1B agree.. Its a large constant even though it is better than 1Bx1B

Comment: To me a distributed merge sort is the way to go for this. Worst case comparisons for merge sort is of the order of `nlog(n)` much better than a large constant x N

Comment: @SomeDude the reason this is still O(n) though is because if instead of a billion numbers you had 10^100 numbers in the input the constant would still be 1M.

Comment: @SomeDude I don't think a distributed merge sort would work here. The task is to select the top `10e6`, doing a merge sort means you are doing more work than necessary since you are finding the order amongst all the elements. Maintaining a min heap is what does the task. It would take `O(2*(log(10e6))` operations to insert a new number and works on a single system. the total approximate time complexity will be `O(10e9 + 10e6 * 2 * log(10e6))` and since `n` over here means `10e9` it can be written as `O(n + n/1000 * 2 * log(n/1000))`. It's not O(n) but it gets as close as possible.

Comment: Ok maintaining a min heap of constant number of elements from a stream of elements 1B or 10^200 is the right thing to do and 1 M elements should fit comfortably in today's RAM. Someone post an answer then.

Comment: @SomeDude Also it is `large constant + n` and not `large constant * n`, correct me if I'm wrong @Patrick87?

Comment: @asds_asds it is a multiplying factor - its insertion sort. worst case you need to go through all elements.

Comment: I am talking about a min heap based approach.

Comment: @asds_asds The min heap approach actually has a small multiplicative constant, since it only requires a peek 999/1000's of the time, and heap ops proportional to log(1M) = 20 in only 1/1000 cases.

Comment: The peek can be done in `O(1)` which can be done as the number is being read. It's a really really small constant (just a comparison) and the rest is as you said earlier.

Comment: I’d like to weigh in on this, but I’m confused what the OP is asking. Their question references 100, 1000000, and 1000000000 in a way I can’t interpret. Can you edit the question to clarify what the OP is trying to do?

Comment: @templatetypedef I think I can just rollback the last edit(s). The original version made sense even if it was a slightly strange question.

Answer (score 0):

You can *generally* do better than sorting. Most people would solve this problem by using a heap as the structure. The time complexity to build the heap will be O(n). But you will then have to do a million "pop" operations, the time complexity for each pop being O(log n), but you are not doing the full n pops (only n/1000 pops in this case).

I say you can "generally" do better than sorting because most sorting algorithms in libraries are O(n log n). But there is the "distribution sort" that is actually O(n + k), where k is the number of possible values in the range you are sorting and depending on the value of k, you *might* do better sorting.

**Update**

To incorporate the suggestion made by @pjs, create a "minimum" heap with the first million values from the billion where a pop operation removes the minimum value from the heap. Then for the next 999,000,000 values, check to see if each one is greater than the current minimum value on the heap and if so, pop the current minimum value from the heap and push the new value. When you are done, you will be left with the 1,000,000 largest values.

Comment: Don't make a heap containing the billion, store a million and then replace the min whenever the next candidate from the billion is bigger than the current min.  When you get to the end, the heap contains your largest million.

Comment: @pjs Depending on the order of the initial numbers, do we know for a fact that this would always be faster? The initial "heapify" algorithm against a billion numbers could be faster than the N "push" operations you would have to do (not sure what the expected value for N is against random data).

Comment: On average only 1 in 1000 values would end up pushed onto the smaller heap.  You just skip right past the others.

Comment: @pjs  So normally to solve the OP's problem you use a "max" heap to get the 1 million largest numbers. But to determine what the current "min" is from this heap you would then need separate bookkeeping. But then how would you replace it since you can only pop off the largest number? That implies what you really want then is a "min" heap.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been saying in my comments on other answers.  If you read them, you'll see that no additional bookkeeping is needed.  After processing the billion values with a min heap of a million as described in those comments, at the end the heap contains the million largest values from the set of a billion.

Comment: What's the worst-case input for this? For the worst-case input, what are the terms and constants?

Comment: @Patrick87 If the data is sorted in ascending order, then my original method of creating the initial heap of 1 billion is sure to be more efficient than doing 999,000,000 push operations. Everything else depends on the implementation and hardware,

Comment: And if you're allowed to modify the input array (as you would do with quickselect), you can do this in place. Simply rearrange the first 1 million items in the array to be in heap order. Then do the standard heap selection with the rest of the items.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, most "heapify" algorithms such as Python's work in place but you can't, unfortunately, pass to it a length saying to just heapify the first N elements. You will first have to take a "slice" and copy into a new list.

Comment: Or just write your own partial heap implementation. All you need is the build-heap, and a sift down.

Comment: Worst case input would be an array in ascending order because every item would result in replacing the root, and it would be sifted down to the very bottom level of the heap. The complexity of this algorithm is O(n log k), and every n would require log(k) level moves.

Comment: @JimMischel If you look 5 comments up I addressed the worst-case performance. If you did the heapify in place on the original n = 1 billion elements it would be only O(n). for the heapify (there really isn't much of a worst-case scenario for that). Of course, you still need to to 1 million pop operations but overall it would be the way to go if you knew you had this degenerate case.

Comment: "If you knew you had this degenerate case." But if you knew you had the degenerate case, you could just swap the first and last million items . . .

Comment: @JimMischel Clearly. The only point I am making is that there are cases (not necessarily *that* degenerate) where it would be quicker to heapify all n numbers in a max heap and then pop, pop, pop ...